# Using shiny modules and shinydashboard: shiny.tag error

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create and use shiny modules inside a shinydashboard app but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
```

Here is the app as condensed as possible:

### ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

source("modules.r")

ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(
  title = "Shiny modules and shinydashboard"
 ),

 dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
   menuItem("PointA") 
  )
 ),

 dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
   fooUI("myid") 
  )
 )
)
```

### server.r

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 callModule(foo, "myid") 
}
```

### modules.r

```
fooUI <- function(id) {
 ns <- NS(id)

 tagList(
  tabItem(
   tabName = "PointA",
   textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
 )
}

foo <- function(input, output, session){

 output$text <- renderText(
  rnorm(1)
 )
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I got other kinds of modules to work in a "normal" shiny app, however, whenever I try to use a module within shinydashboard it fails.

I am using the newest version of `R`, `shiny` and `shinydashboard`. This is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with `shinydashboard` and `tagList`

As described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/IfNpMsvFgkg)

You need simple use

```
   ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Shiny modules and shinydashboard"
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("PointA",tabName = "PointA") 
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tags$div( fooUI("myid"), class = "tab-content" )

)
)
```

## Update

You also need `tabName` in `menuItem`

```
menuItem("PointA_",tabName = "PointA")
```

## Explanation

As you can see

```
tabItems
function (...) 
{
    lapply(list(...), tagAssert, class = "tab-pane")
    div(class = "tab-content", ...)
}
<environment: namespace:shinydashboard>
```

use `list` to `...` and cant work if you already have list as arg.

So other variant it create new tabItems function like

```
tabItems1=function (...) 
    {
        lapply(..., tagAssert, class = "tab-pane")
        div(class = "tab-content", ...)
    }
environment(tabItems1)=environment(tabItems)
```

And then you can use `tabItems1` with `tagList`

Comment: Using `tags$div( fooUI("myid"), class = "tab-content" )` does not work. I get: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected tag to have class 'tab-pane`. When I change the class attribute to `"tab-pane"` I get the app to run but no content is shown..

Comment: But this is the right direction, so thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Your second solution (redfining `tabItems` seems to work)....its kind of ugly though...

Comment: Hmm.. strange add full UI for first variant, it also not work?

Answer (score 0):

Following @Batanichek's answer which pointed me to the source of the problem (thanks for that) I simply removed the `tagList()` command in my `fooUI` definition. This conveniently solves the problem!

Comment: Without tagList you cant use more than one element in fooUI

Comment: Hmm yes i just realized that :-(

Comment: Seems this error `Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag' `comes not just in your specific  scenario but a general probelm in shinydashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Seems tabName is necessary in the menuItem function
2. Move tabItem from the module to ui (tabItem can hold you module)

**UI**

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Shiny modules and shinydashboard"
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("PointA", tabName = "PointA") 
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("PointA",
              fooUI("myid")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**Module**

```
fooUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    tabName = "PointA",
    textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
}

foo <- function(input, output, session){

  output$text <- renderText(
    rnorm(1)
  )
}
```