# Shiny dashboard and DT table not showing

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have a dashboard where I would like to show a table, but I cant figure out why my table is not showing. If I replace the table for example with some text, `h2(....)` it does show. I would like to click on "Species" and have the table show on the right when clicking it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      "Species",
      tabName = "Species",
      icon = NULL,
      switchInput(
        inputId = "long1",
        onLabel = "Go",
        offLabel = "NoGo",
        value = T
      ),
      actionButton("Gobtn", "Get data"),
      menuItem("Specs", tabName = "Specs", icon = NULL)
    )
  )),

  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Species",
            DT::renderDataTable("Table1")),
    tabItem(tabName = "Specs",
            h2("Hi"))
  ))
)
```

---

**server.r**

```
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    iris
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things to get your code up and running here. Couple have been noted by other contributors.

We need to use `DT::dataTableOutput("Table1")` on the UI side as `renderDataTable` will not work here, that is the server side function.

The other would be that using the `switchInput` within the `menuItem` may confused the app, as these are not standard parameters to pass into the function. From what I can see from your code, which is a common challenge, is that you want to be able to show this `switchInput` only when the 'Species' tab is selected. We can account for this using `conditionalPanel`. To do this, we can set `id = "tabs"` within the `sidebarMenu` and then reference this `sidebarMenu` within the `conditionalPanel`:

```
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.tabs== 'Species' ",
  switchInput(
    inputId = "long1",
    onLabel = "Go",
    offLabel = "NoGo",
    value = T
  )
)
```

To finish, I have altered the layouts of the ui.R and server.R, as the `shinyApp` function was not needed for the app to work with the server and ui files. This is how I lay out my dashboards. It may show you a few other possible ways you can use the app structure within Shiny, but equally you could just align the changes to the basic layout.

**ui.R**

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
    menuItem(
      "Species",
      tabName = "Species",
      icon = NULL),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabs== 'Species' ",
      switchInput(
        inputId = "long1",
        onLabel = "Go",
        offLabel = "NoGo",
        value = T
      )
    ),


    actionButton("Gobtn", "Get data"),

    menuItem("Specs", tabName = "Spec", icon = NULL)
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Species",
            DT::dataTableOutput("Table1")),

    tabItem(tabName = "Spec",
            h2("Hi"))
  )
)

dashboardPage(skin = "blue", header = header, sidebar = sidebar, body = body)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris)
  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it not possible to make the menuitems collapsable?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. However, yes you can make collapsible menus, using menuSubItems or passing javascript into the script / using another menu type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change/add some part of the `dashboardBody`, see [Using shiny modules and shinydashboard: shiny.tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593552/using-shiny-modules-and-shinydashboard-shiny-tag-error)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      "Species",
      tabName = "Species",
      icon = NULL,

      switchInput(
        inputId = "long1",
        onLabel = "Go",
        offLabel = "NoGo",
        value = T
      ),
      actionButton("Gobtn", "Get data")
    )
  )),

  dashboardBody(tags$div(
    tabName = "Species",
    fluidRow(box(DT::dataTableOutput("Table1"))), class = "tab-content"
  ))
  )
```

---

**server.r**

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    iris
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: sorry, I missed a "," after icon = NULL. I updated the code a bit, the thing is I would like to have the table shown under "Species" tab when I click on it. Right now, when I click on the tab, the button options appear but nothing on the right changes.

Comment: @user6617474 Your item works perfect, but can you show how to do if I have several tabs as in my example? Because I cant get it to work when I increase number of tabs